# How to stop Vim hanging until keypress?

Tags: vimrc

For context: I'm only getting started with `vimrc`s. I just installed Vim on a second machine. On this machine, I don't have admin privileges. However, I've managed to install Vim and gVim 8.2 in the user-specific directory, and added the `Vim/vim82` directory to the user-specific Path.

Since I installed with all enhancements loaded, there was a `vimrc_example.vim` and that was sourced in my `Vim/_vimrc`. I fully deleted everything within this `_vimrc`.

I loaded Vim from the Windows 10 Command Prompt: `vim`. It worked normally and the main screen came up.

Then, I added these lines to my `_vimrc` - these are the only lines inside it:

```
set nu
set noerrorbells
set tabstop = 4
set colorscheme blue
```

Now I run Vim and it just hangs - a black window - until I press any key. Then the main screen comes up.

Is there any way to get this back to normal so I don't have to press a key to get Vim to stop hanging?

**Edit**: Upon further inspection, it's when I add the line `set colorscheme blue` that the hanging begins. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Does it still happen with `vim --clean`? Is there something in `:messages`? Have you checked `:scriptnames` to see if there isn't another configuration file loaded with something which might cause the issue?

Comment: @statox Deleting all the lines in the ```_vimrc``` then running Vim again fixes it, so that's why I'm suspicious of it.

Comment: PS should be `set tabstop=4` for the correct syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the answer is in `set colorscheme blue` which should just read `colorscheme blue`.

Further reading on changing colours can be found in `:h usr_06` and `:h :colorscheme`.

Comment: That fixed it. I should have known since in Command Mode you just type ```:colorscheme <scheme>```. I thought you had to put ```set``` in front of everything in a ```_vimrc```.

Comment: Ah that's a good catch!